# How to define empty DataSource depending on param in URL in Xpage?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, ssjs

Design pattern in my Xpages application looks like below. When I in list view, I want to call dominoDocument1 for print and expect return null, because dominoDocument do not have key(documentId in url), but return UNID.I want this behavior for global custom control what can delete how in view mode and how in form mode. In form_toolbar component I what do something with dominoDocument and that`s why my dominoDocument define above another components.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="dominoDocument1" formName="sample"
            concurrencyMode="force" action="openDocument">
            <xp:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var object1 = new SamplesDB();
object1.getDBPath();}]]></xp:this.databaseName>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/dbClass.jss" clientSide="false"></xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xc:resources></xc:resources>
    <xc:global_left_sidebar></xc:global_left_sidebar>
    <xc:layout_content>
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xc:form_toolbar xp:key="sample_form"></xc:form_toolbar>
            <xc:view_toolbar xp:key="sample_view"></xc:view_toolbar>
            <xc:form_toolbar xp:key="sample_to_researches_table"></xc:form_toolbar>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xc:layout_content>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <xc:layout_content>
                <xp:this.facets>
                    <xc:sample_form xp:key="sample_form"></xc:sample_form>
                    <xc:sample_view xp:key="sample_view"></xc:sample_view>
                    <xc:cc_sample_to_researches_table
                        xp:key="sample_to_researches_table">
                    </xc:cc_sample_to_researches_table>
                </xp:this.facets>
            </xc:layout_content>
        </div>
    </div>
</xp:view>
```

w>

Comment: I do not fully understand your issue. If you do not include the documentId in the URL as a parameter, you need to calculcate "documentId" on the xp:dominoDocument data source instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the XPages application as a stand alone NSF for only one purpose, a web UI, and leave all the legacy Notes and new NSF data as data repositories for the UI.

-XPages UI NSF-
I think its best to create a 'Managed Bean' in faces-config, such as App.java and name it 'app'.  Then create a DominoService.java that gets and sets data to the database NSF.

Design Java model objects, plain old Java objects that are in between the NSF and XPages UI.  Reuse in other XPages projects.

On start, the server instantiates the Java objects in faces-config.

You also can can add Action Listeners to events that will do some work like get all documents from a view and return a ArrayList and that 'persons' is what is the in the 'value' property of a <xp:repeat /> or <xp:table /> component.

You will will want your XPages UI components to bind to Plain Java objects and lists for data.

The benefit you can always switch out the backend, for example, instead of writing and reading from a Key/Value pair NSF data store you can create a NoSQLHelper.java or SQLHelper.java and implement the same methods from the DominoService.java and the UI does not change.